# Pipeline (Pypiper) returns error, but individual command works fine

Tags: rna-seq

I am running a script file on a cluster with `slurm` through `sbatch`. Locally it runs perfectly well on 2 different linux versions (`linux mint`, `ubuntu 12.04`), however, it returns `-9` error code while running on a cluster which is `CentOS 7.3`. When we are using `Pypiper` and run the whole `.py` script file, it fails when it starts running `trimmomatic` program

http://www.usadellab.org/cms/?page=trimmomatic

However, when running just `trimmomatic` program step by itself it does not fail and finishes successfully. We have a suspicion that something may be wrong with how `Pypiper` runs on the cluster, however, feeling rather stuck.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error that is printed out:

```
ILLUMINACLIP: Using 2 prefix pairs, 22 forward/reverse sequences, 0 
forward only sequences, 0 reverse only sequences
</pre>
Process 109391 returned: (-9). Elapsed: 0:00:51. Peak memory: (Process: 
5.211GB; Pipeline: 0.0GB)

### Pipeline failed at:  (12-14 15:50:47) elapsed:0:23:09 _TIME_

Total time: 0:23:09

Change status from running to failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...../salmon_rna_seq.py", line 344, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "...../salmon_rna_seq.py", line 304, in main
pipeline.process()      
File "...../salmon_rna_seq.py", line 277, in process
self.trim_reads()      
File "...../salmon_rna_seq.py", line 195, in trim_reads
self.pipe_manager.run(cmd, self.sample_files['r1']['fastq']['trimmed_paired'])
File "...../pypiper.py", line 508, in run
process_return_code, local_maxmem = self.callprint(cmd, shell, nofail, container)  # Run command
File "...../pypiper.py", line 691, in callprint
self.fail_pipeline(e)
File "...../pypiper.py", line 1111, in fail_pipeline
raise e
OSError: Subprocess returned nonzero result.

Pypiper terminating spawned child process 108475...
child process terminated
slurmstepd: error: Exceeded step memory limit at some point.
```

The last line may be informative. Although, we are still not sure what we could possibly do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slurm is killing the process because it's using more memory per core than the default allocation (that's what `slurmstepd: error: Exceeded step memory limit at some point` means). I've never used pyPiper (like seemingly most people, I use snakemake), but presuming that you have it running either `srun` or `sbatch` at some point then specify something like `--mem-per-cpu 10G`.

Comment: Actually I tried that and it still does not work. Will try to write to the cluster support

Comment: You might need a larger value than 10 gigs. You can use `scontrol` to see the exact threshold getting crossed that's causing slurm to kill the job.

Comment: Awesome. We increased it to 20Gb and it run successfully.